# T-SQL Query Join on different column depending on case

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a legacy system that has a sales table and a customer table, CMS and CUST respectively.  I need to query for the shipped to address based on different criteria.  The customer table treats each address as its own customer.  So if I have a billing address, then a shipping address, those will both be different CUSTNUM's.  The CMS table has columns CUSTNUM and SHIPNUM.  If the sales order uses the billing address as the shipping address, SHIPNUM = 0.  If those 2 address are different, SHIPNUM = a different customer number than CUSTNUM.  I'm trying to write a query that joins CUST to CMS based on the case of SHIPNUM being > 0 or not.  My original query just used CUSTNUM, and ignored the SHIPNUM.  My new query is syntactically correct and executes, but the row count returned is 2860 vs 3590 for the old query. The old join statement is just the commented out line :ON CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST.CUSTNUM.

```
from
        KGI_LOTNOS as LOT
        INNER JOIN CMS
                ON LOT.ORDERNO = CMS.ORDERNO
        JOIN CUST
                ON CUST.CUSTNUM = 
                        CASE
                                WHEN CMS.SHIPNUM > 0
                                        THEN CMS.SHIPNUM
                                Else CMS.CUSTNUM
                                END
--                ON CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST.CUSTNUM
        INNER JOIN COUNTRY as C
                ON CUST.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY
```

Here is an example from the CMS table;

```
CUSTNUM SHIPNUM ORDERNO
41863   77394   828509  <--Different billing and shipping address
43242   69291   776888  <--Different billing and shipping address
2356    0   765022  <--Same billing and shipping address
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

PS Here is the original query in its entirety.

```
select
        CUST.CUSTNUM as Customer,
        CMS.CUSTNUM,
        CMS.SHIPNUM,
        CUST.CTYPE,
        CMS.ORDERNO,
        CMS.ODR_DATE,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.FIRSTNAME)) as First,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.LASTNAME)) as Last,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.COMPANY)) as Company,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.PHONE)) as Phone,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.EMAIL)) as Email,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.ADDR)) as ADDR1,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.ADDR2)) as ADDR2,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.ADDR3)) as ADDR3,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.CITY)) as City,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.State)) as State,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.ZIPCODE)) as Zip,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(C.NAME)) as Country,
        LOT.ITEMNO,
        LOT.LOTNO,
        COUNT(LOT.ITEMNO) as Quantity
from
KGI_LOTNOS as LOT
INNER JOIN CMS
   ON LOT.ORDERNO = CMS.ORDERNO
LEFT JOIN CUST
   ON CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST.CUSTNUM
INNER JOIN COUNTRY as C
   ON CUST.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY 
where
          (
               CUST.CTYPE IN ('P','W','Z')
          )
        AND
                (
                        LOT.LOTNO IN ('1000001','20001','300001')
                )
GROUP BY 
        CMS.ORDERNO,
        CUST.CUSTNUM,
        CMS.CUSTNUM,
        CMS.SHIPNUM,
        CUST.CTYPE,
        CUST.FIRSTNAME,
        CMS.ODR_DATE,
        CUST.LASTNAME,
        CUST.COMPANY,
        CUST.PHONE,
        CUST.EMAIL,
        CUST.ADDR,
        CUST.ADDR2,
        CUST.ADDR3,
        LOT.ITEMNO,
        CUST.CITY,
        CUST.STATE,
        CUST.ZIPCODE,
        C.NAME,
        LOT.LOTNO
ORDER BY
        Customer,
        CMS.ORDERNO,
        LOT.ITEMNO,
        LOT.LOTNO
```

Comment: Thinking out of the box as I'm still not sure what's wrong with your query, but do you have any NULL's in SHIPNUM or negative numbers?

Comment: Hard to see from what you've posted but I'd union two joins, one for each if I needed something like that.

Comment: I did check for Null's, there weren't any.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `INNER JOIN` you have risk to exclude raws which have no reference in another table. This could be caused by any of 2 another joins in your expression - comment them and try again. If you still receive less records you should check consistency of your data - one table has values which not correspond to values in another table.

BTW, I don't like `CASE` in `JOIN` expression simply because it looks ugly. What do you thinK about this expression which seemed to do the job too:

```
 LEFT JOIN CUST
      ON CUST.CUSTNUM = COALESCE(NULLIF(CMS.SHIPNUM, 0), CMS.CUSTNUM)
```

Comment: I tried this and it returned the same 2806 records.  My original join that works but doesn't return the shipping address returns 3590.

Comment: @MLindsay: Could you provide your original join? Did you use `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Modified the original to include the full query.  Long weekend, sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: You have `GROUP BY` clause this can cause such difference. Comment `GROUP BY` and try to run `SELECT` with original `JOIN` and new one. You should obtain equal number of records as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Fewer records join using your altered criteria, there are some `CMS.SHIPNUM` values that don't have matching `CUSTNUM` in the `CUST` table.

To find the problematic entries change from `INNER` to `OUTER` join and add `WHERE` criteria, something like:

```
  LEFT JOIN CUST
      ON CUST.CUSTNUM =  CASE  WHEN CMS.SHIPNUM > 0 THEN CMS.SHIPNUM
                               ELSE CMS.CUSTNUM
                         END
  WHERE CUST.CUSTNUM IS NULL
      AND CMS.SHIPNUM > 0
```

Edit:  You'll have to remove the `INNER JOIN` to `COUNTRY` to see the unmatched from your updated `JOIN` since it joins on a field from the customer table, and make sure to have the `SHIPNUM` field in your `SELECT`.

Comment: Returned 0 rows.  If I dropped off the where clauses, it returned the same 2860.  To make sure I understand what you had me do, I was searching for records that were not in my original query correct?  That means each SHIPNUM found a match in the customers table?

Comment: @MLindsay That was the goal, to find the unmatched, see my edit to the answer above, you'll have to remove the join to `COUNTRY` to see the records that don't match between your old and new criteria.

Comment: @MLindsay, if you are still getting 2860 rows with the query suggested above, it could be that in your original query, some of the CUSTNUM in Cust matched more than one CUSTNUM in CMS. Thus multiple rows with the same CUSTNUM were returned in your original query.

Comment: In my query, I will have multiple records with the same customer number. In my results, Order Number is what I am grouping by.  From my thinking, the 2 queries should return identical # of results, except with different customer numbers.

Comment: @MLindsay Did you run the query above with the join to `COUNTRY` removed to see if there are any `SHIPNUM` values that don't have a matching `CUST.CUSTNUM`?

Comment: Yes, the CUST.CUSTNUM is never Null, it returns 0 records if I include that.  If I just use CMS.SHIPNUM > 0 then it returns 509 records, which I do see in my 2860 (spot checked).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE like this.

WITH cte (ORDERNO, SHIPNUM) AS
( 
  SELECT ORDERNUM, SHIPNUM = CASE 
WHEN CMS.SHIPNUM > 0

FROM CMS

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

your query looks correct but not sure why it is not working, try left joinCUST table twiceone on shipping and the other on billing and then write the case statement for each customer column.

```
select
 LTRIM(RTRIM(case when CMS.SHIPNUM > 0 THEN CUST.FIRSTNAME else CUST_BILL.FIRSTNAME end  )) as First,
from
    KGI_LOTNOS as LOT
    INNER JOIN CMS
            ON LOT.ORDERNO = CMS.ORDERNO
    left JOIN CUST CUST
            ON CUST.CUSTNUM = CMS.SHIPNUM 
     left JOIN CUST CUST_BILL      
          ON CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST_BILL.CUSTNUM
    INNER JOIN COUNTRY as C
            ON CUST.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY
```

if it still outputs less rows then something else is wrong

Comment: Messing around with this.  It will always be cust.firstname, there isn't a cust_bill.firstname type thing.  The order table (CMS) changes cms.shipnumber to reflect an actual customer in the customer table.  Will let you know what I find.

Comment: CUST_BILL was the alias i have created for CUST table, missed the actual table name which i have corrected it now see above